# Android SDK installed failed: SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-manager

I have my first basic "Hello World" app written in Node/TypeScript/React/Ionic and I am trying to see if I can get it running as a native Android app. The idea is that I'd like the app to run on my personal (**Samsung Galaxy S10, Android v12**) phone.

I have installed Android Studio (2021.3.1 Patch 1) and am now trying to make sure that my Android SDK setup meets two criteria:

- Will produce an APK/native executable that can run on my phone; and
- Has everything that my version of Ionic v6.20.4 needs

So, after installing API level 31 I get the following error:

[image]

When I look in `idea.log` I see:

```
2022-11-28 15:07:23,298 [263621647]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Read timed out. 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:461)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:985)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3514)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3507)
    at com.intellij.util.net.NetUtils.copyStreamContent(NetUtils.java:186)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.lambda$doDownloadFully$2(StudioDownloader.java:229)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:516)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:498)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:333)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.doDownloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:219)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFullyWithCaching(StudioDownloader.java:154)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:74)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:335)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:269)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:496)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:244)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-11-28 15:07:23,305 [263621654]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (revision: 4)" failed.
```

**What went wrong and whats the fix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minSdkVersion` should be `Android 12 (API level 31)` or less than 31 if you want to support older devices. so you should choose Android 12 (API level 31) check box.

Also if you want to upload your app to Google Play your `targetSdkVersion` [should be](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk) `Android 12 (API level 31)` or higher. so you should choose also the SDK you want to target.

> Starting in November 2022, app updates must target API level 31 or above

> The min sdk version is the earliest release of the Android SDK that your application can run on. Usually this is because of a problem with the earlier APIs, lacking functionality, or some other behavioural issue.
>
> The target sdk version is the version your application was targeted to run on.

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Please ask me any question you want to be answer since I do to know what is your level in Android Development.

Comment: Thanks @Jabbar (+1) -- please see my update above. Any idea why Android Studio would fail to install an SDK like that?

Comment: Just try again, installing packages is the most straight forward steps, I think there is nothing wrong from your side